# Create custom TabItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabs

I want to create a custom tabitem in my project with a treeview and stackpanel inside that Tab item. I am new to WPF. Please suggest me how this can be done.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <DockPanel>
            <TreeView/>
            <StackPanel />
        </DockPanel>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```